# DBMS SQL Database Query

Tags: mysql

How to view this?

Problem: The oldest student per `sProgram`.

Table name is `Student`.

Columns are:

```
sID, sLast, sFirst, sMI, sProgram, sGender, sAge
```

Sample data:

```
sID    sLast    sFirst   sMI   sProgram  sGender   sAge
-------------------------------------------------------
001    Right    Mc       D     BSIT         M       26   
002    Michael  John     G     BSIT         M       22  
002    Franco   James    D     BSCPE        M       20   
003    Step     Ren      D     BSECE        M       22
```

I want to display the oldest student of BSIT

The desired output is :

```
001 , Right, Mc, D, BSIT, M, 26
```

Comment: Have you tried querying for the data you need yet...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want oldest student of 'BSID', you can try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Student
WHERE sProgram = 'BSIT'
ORDER BY sAge DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Or if you want oldest student of each `sProgram`, you can do it like this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Student t1
JOIN (
    SELECT sProgram, MAX(sAge) AS sAge FROM Student GROUP BY sProgram
) t2 ON t1.sProgram = t2.sProgram AND t1.sAge = t2.sAge
-- WHERE t1.sProgram = 'BSIT'
```